# get_cost_and_usage MatchOptions in AWS Boto3 is not working for "starts_with"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to get get_cost_and_usage results for a tag filter that starts with a specific string.

```
                       filter_list.append({
                            'Tags': {
                                'Key': 'test_config_name',
                                'MatchOptions': ['STARTS_WITH'],
                                'Values': ["test"],
                            },
                        })
```

```
            data = self.ce_client.get_cost_and_usage(
                TimePeriod={'Start': start, 'End': end},
                Granularity='MONTHLY',
                Metrics=['UnblendedCost'],
                Filter=filters,
                GroupBy=[groupby],
                **kwargs
            )
```

The above code is giving an error as
`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetCostAndUsage operation: MatchOptions contain not allowed match option. Allowed MatchOptions:CASE_SENSITIVE, EQUALS, ABSENT`

How can I get the results that are starting with a specific string

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, the [Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_cost_and_usage) states you *can* while the AWS [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetCostAndUsage.html#API_GetCostAndUsage_RequestParameters) says you *can't*.

But as the Boto3 SDK (alongside all other AWS SDKs) use the AWS API, and the error also confirms what the API docs say, the only allowed `MatchOptions` are:

1. `CASE_SENSITIVE`
2. `EQUALS`
3. `ABSENT`

There is no `STARTS_WITH`.

Not sure why the Boto3 documentation is wrong here.

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_cost_and_usage

The link also says that the option is allowed

Comment: Is there an alternate way we can get the value that starts with a specific string

Comment: I tried using Regex but 'Values': ["^Aarch"] also does not work

Comment: Is there an alternate way we can get the value that starts with a specific string?

Comment: @ArunKumar Not that I'm aware of.